# detect android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT

Tags: javascript, android

I'm trying to use android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT in a script.

```
<script>
  var version = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
  if (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("android") != -1) && (version < 11) {
     doThis();
  } else {
     doThat();
  }
</script>
```

The var doesn't set on android phone and can't figure out why. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Have you think is script done such kind of things ?

Comment: Not quite sure what you are asking.